# iOS Apple Pay - Customize PKPaymentButton

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I'm using **PKPaymentButton** for ApplePay integration but want to know if I can customize it easily.

```
let applePayButton = PKPaymentButton(type: PKPaymentButtonType.setUp, style: PKPaymentButtonStyle.black)
```

1. Can we change the button style?
   After setup of ApplePay, I wanted to change the buttonType to .buy but didn't find a solution.
2. Can we remove corner radius?
   Default ApplePay button has corner radius. I don't like it and tried to remove it. So, I tried to work with layer but it didn't work.

   ```
   applePayButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0
   ```

Please let me know if I can change the ApplePay button properties easily.

Comment: There's always a chance Apple won't allow modifying the appearance of the button on purpose, perhaps to avoid confusion (malicious or otherwise).

Comment: But I'm just going to use properties which Apple supports.

Comment: I know. All I'm saying is, perhaps they're making an exception with this button -and ignoring public API property changes to it- in an (exaggerated) effort to protect their customers.  But it's just a guess,based on Apple's typical m.o. I do not have an answer to your question.

Comment: I understand. Please let me know if you find the good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes you can change it by recreating PKPaymentButton with different PKPaymentButtonStyle in runtime. Or you can write your own PKPaymentButton wrapper that will do it for you.
2. Though Apple doesn't recommend to alter Apple Pay Button appearance, it's doable. Again, using your PKPaymentButton wrapper, place Apple Pay button in the center and alter corner radius of your wrapper button, you can change size of icons in that way too. I did it in some of my projects and didn't get a word from Apple.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the appearance of the button with his runtime attributes:

```
    [self.applePayButton setValue:@(0) forKey:@"style"];
```

Pass 0 for a black button and 2 for a white Apple Pay Button

Answer (score -1):

In the [Apple Pay Identity Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Apple-Pay-Identity-Guidelines.pdf), Apple states that you should **not** change the corner radius of the Apple Pay button (PKPaymentButton).

Comment: Yes, we cannot change the corner radius. But we cannot change the button type also?

Comment: To change the button style, you will need to re-create the PKPaymentButton

Comment: Corner radius restrictions seem to only apply to the artwork provided in the assets they make available, not the Apple Pay PKPaymentButton. Also, it would be really weird for that class to have a corner radius property if it was not meant to be used.